# How can I turn this into a loop?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, parameters

I'm trying to make this even cleaner, I've shortened dozens of lines to this, but need to loop through my column/dropdown values and run them through the function. I'm blanking.

```
function populateDropdowns (dropdownObject) {
$.ajax({
    url: "website eq '"+dropdownObject.column+"'",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var authOne = (data.d.results[0].Choices.results);
            $(dropdownObject.dropdown).empty();
            $.each(authOne, function(i, p) {
                $(dropdownObject.dropdown).append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
            });
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
var dropdownObject = {};
dropdownObject = {column:"value1", dropdown:'#id1'}; populateDropdowns(dropdownObject);
dropdownObject = {column:"value2", dropdown:'#id2'}; populateDropdowns(dropdownObject);
dropdownObject = {column:"value3", dropdown:'#id3'}; populateDropdowns(dropdownObject);
dropdownObject = {column:"value4", dropdown:'#id4'}; populateDropdowns(dropdownObject);
dropdownObject = {column:"value5", dropdown:'#id5'}; populateDropdowns(dropdownObject);
```

Comment: Loop from 1 to 5 and use concatenation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your values are fixed till 5, then a for loop should work fine.

```
for(var i = 1; i < 6; i++){
    populateDropdowns( {column : "value" + i, dropdown:'#id' + i});
}
```

**EDIT 1:** If values are not sequential, then you can pass Objects array to a `forEach` loop.

```
var dropdowns = [
  {column: "value1", dropdown: "#id1"},
  {column: "value2", dropdown: "#id2"},
  {column: "value3", dropdown: "#id3"},
  {column: "value4", dropdown: "#id4"},
  {column: "value5", dropdown: "#id5"}
;

dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => populateDropdowns(dropdown));
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I should have specified that these values aren't sequential. They're all unique.

Comment: Can you post true names and ids or a rule for detecting.them?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through some data, the data should probably be in an array:

```
const dropdownObjects = [
  { column: 'value1', dropdown: '#id1' },
  { column: 'value2', dropdown: '#id2' },
  { column: 'value3', dropdown: '#id3' },
  // ...
];

for (var i = 0; i < dropdownObjects.length; i++) {
  populateDropdowns(dropdownObjects[i]);
}
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
dropdownObjects.forEach(populateDropdowns);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer as well.